# Editing expired entries from the front end

Tags: saveentry, entry-form, expired

I'm trying to edit an expired entry from the front end.

However, when I hit save, none of the changes persist and a redirect doesn't take place.

Entries that have a live status are fine. Even when I modify the `postDate` and `expiryDate` manually, it doesn't update.

I was using the [auto-expire](https://github.com/carlcs/craft-autoexpire) plugin and it works fine for new entries. Even disabling it temporarily, the editing of expired entries fails.

Have even stripped out all required fields

```
<form id="jobForm" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
        {{ getCsrfInput() }}
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="entries/saveEntry">
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="{slug}/{id}">
        <input type="hidden" name="entryId" value="{{ entry.id }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="sectionId" value="3">
        <input type="hidden" name="enabled" value="1">
        <p> <label for="Date">Date</label>
                <input type="date" id="postDate" name="postDate" value="{{ entry.postDate }}">
        </p>
        <p><label for="Expiry">Expiry</label>
            <input type="date" id="expiryDate" name="expiryDate" value="{{ entry.expiryDate }}">
        </p>
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input id="title" type="text" name="title"
                {%- if entry is defined %} value="{{ entry.title }}"{% endif -%}>

        {% if entry is defined %}
            {{ errorList(entry.getErrors('title')) }}
        {% endif %}

        <input type="submit" value="Publish">
    </form>
```

Has something changed in Craft because it did work on older versions?

Comment: If you dump `entry.getErrors()` after trying to submit, does it return anything?

Comment: No, tried that with no joy either.